# Helping my family sell their oil stocks. What to buy?

Tags: stocks, investing, bonds

sorry I'm a bit new to the investing world. I am familiar with most topic from my business minor.

My family has a lot of their retirement in oil company stock. (I know, diversify.. they don't know) I'm looking at the over supply of oil, China's money play, the Iran deal, and the incredible rate the stocks are falling (20% this month).. I'm thinking I need to help my family sell all their stocks, and put it into something more stable. I was thinking bonds. I also want them to be free to purchase the stock again, once the majority of it's fall is finished. Any advice or resources I can point my family to? I know my family wont want government bonds. Was thinking lots of well off tech companies. The bonds are more or less to prevent triggering capital gains taxes. Until they can rebuy the stock at a lower price.

Thanks!

Comment: By selling the stock, you will trigger capital gains taxes, regardless of what you buy afterwards. Or are you talking about capital gains from something else?

Comment: If you are looking for specific recommendations, that's out of scope for this discussion. If you are looking for general advice on interesting distribution, that would be on topic, but there are many past answers addressing it. Can you be more specific?

Comment: If you sell a bond for more than you paid for it you have to pay a capital gains tax.

Comment: Guess I was thinking of houses, in that if you reinvest you don't trigger a gain. Hmm

Comment: reinvesting of capital gains from the sale of a house ended in the 1990's

Comment: Wouldn't buying the stock of "well off tech companies" be a case of "Buying High" possibly followed by a "Selling Low"? Also, are these oil company stocks inside a tax-deferred package such as a 401(k) or 403(b) plan or an IRA, or are they held in taxable accounts? This would make a big difference to the capital gains taxes angle; which did not occur to you at all (not covered in the courses in your business minor, presumably).

Comment: What makes you think there's more downside to the oil company? All the stuff you mentioned everyone knows, so why isn't it all priced in? Take Chevron, for instance. It's down what, 43% from a year ago? It's down so much the dividend yield is a whopping 5.65%.  Who knows, it might even be a buy at these levels.

Comment: Also, tech is at/just past a top, it's due a reversal for a while.

Comment: Hah it was a minor. It covered what bonds, etc were and how to do calculations. Not much past that. But I'm smart enough to know to talk to people before taking an action ;-). The capital gains will make this interesting. I do not know personally whats in 401k but I will find out... The dividend is a good point as well. I was thinking about putting my own money into oil futures when it goes sub 35 / barrel. But a dividend might be nicer.. But it seems like a poor time to invest, as there is no sign that it's going to slow down for a while..  Exxon just hit a 5 year low today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **The real answer:**

1. Advise them to go to a fee-only* financial adviser to help them create a financial plan for their retirement, and a diversified retirement portfolio reflecting that plan.
2. Under no circumstances tell them what to do.

*("Fee-only" meaning the only money they make is the fee your folks pay directly; no kickbacks from financial products they're selling.)

### **My immediate reaction, i.e., the detailed answer:**

The answer to this is: for God's sake, leave it alone!

I commend you on wanting to help your family avoid more losses. You are right, that having most of one's retirement in one stock or sector is just silly. And again yes, if they're retired, they probably need some bonds.

But here's the thing, if they follow your advise and it doesn't work out, it will be a SERIOUS strain on your relationship. Of course you'll still be a family and they'll still love you, but emotionally, you are the reason they lost the money, and that will an elephant in between you. This is especially the case since we're talking about a lot of money here (presumably), and retirement money to boot.

You must understand the risk you're taking with your relationships. If you/they lose, at best it'll make things awkward, and you'll feel guilty about their impoverished retirement. At worst it can destroy your relationship with your folks.

What about if you win? Won't you be feted and appreciated by your folks for saving them from themselves? Yes, for a short while. Then life moves on. Everything returns to normal.

But here's the thing. You won't win. You can't. Because even if you're right here, and they win, that means both they and you will be eager for you to do it again. And at some point they'll take a hit based on your advise.

Can I be blunt here? You didn't even know that you can't avoid capital gains taxes by reinvesting stock gains. You don't know enough, and worse, you're not experienced enough. I deduce you're either a college student, or a recent grad. Which means you don't have experience investing your own money. You don't know how the market moves, you just know the theory.

You know who you are? You're me, 20 years ago. And thank God my grandparents ignored my advise. I was right about their utilities stocks back then, too. But I know from what I learned in the years afterwards, investing on my own account, that at some point I would have hurt them. And I would have had a very hard time living with that.

So, tell your folks to go visit a fee-only financial adviser to create a retirement plan.

### **Some more notes, and encouragement:**

Perhaps I'm reading into your post, but it seems like you're enthusiastic about investing; stocks, bonds, building wealth, etc. I love that. My advise -- go for it! Pull some money together, and open your own stock account. Do some trading! As much as people grouse about it, the market really is glorious. It's like playing Monopoly, but for keeps. I mean that in the best way possible. It's fun, you can build wealth doing it, and it provides a very useful social purpose.

In the spirit of that, check out these ideas (just for you, not for your folks!), based on ideas in your post:

1. that market moves are usually in anticipation of what will happen with a company, and therefore, is it possible that oil companies are at or near their bottom? What else has just stunk up the room over the last couple of years?
2. that what goes up, must come down, and even really good companies will revert to the mean for a while after they've had a big run up. Tech has had a big multi-year run up. Are they due to let out some air?
3. bonds. ug, what can I say about bonds. Does it make sense to loan the gov money for 10 years at 2%? Or loan someone a mortgage at 4%? Or investment grade corporate bonds at 4%, and junk corp. bond at 6%?
4. and what about gold? It's had a quiet, consolidate-y couple of years, what's up with that? Are people waking up to the fact that it's nothing more than a pretty, largely useless hunk of metal that doesn't produce anything? Or are people waking up to the fact that it's history's most sensible form of money, that can't be manipulated or inflated away by various governments? (I just couldn't resist bringing gold up :) :) :) )

Good luck.

Comment: What you say about bonds is that they're low yield but also low risk. As you reach the point where you're concerned with preserving as well as growing your wealth, bonds become more useful, providing a relatively safe place to park some money to balance the risks you're taking elsewhere. Bonds also tend to move in the opposite direction from stocks, so diversifying into them can smooth out some of the market's bumpier periods .. for example,  I'd have lost (for now) a lot more of my net worth in the current corrections if the bonds weren't quietly chugging along in their part of my portfolio.

Comment: ps: That financial advisor (excellent advice) will almost certainly recommend a mixture of stocks and bonds, and possibly some other vehicles such as REIT.

Comment: +1 especially for that "me 20 years ago" comment. As Mark Twain said, "When I was 16, I thought my father was a fool. When I turned 21, I was surprised to find out how much the old man had learnt in 5 years."

Comment: @keshlam agreed in all points. I just happen to think yields are irrationally tight across the board now. Unless, of course, we have about a decade or so of deflation coming.

Comment: Yields are influenced by interest rates available elsewhere,  Until the fed relaxes quant easing, they're going to stay that way. Plus is we can borrow cheaply and there's low inflation, so arguably it all scales in parallel... but that's pushed a greag deal of money into the stock market where it isn't available for lending. Reinstate the rules keeping banks from playing in the market and force them to be savings-and-loan institutions again, and some of this will correct itself.

Comment: The issue is the financial adviser thus far has only cost them lots of money. Trusting someone else to do your trading is poor, because I'm seeing he's mostly concerned about losing customers, and doesn't want them all to liquidate. Conflicting interests. But theres a few flaws in your logic. You're under the premis I can only mess up. If they bought all bonds, then they are safer. I only risk them losing a upswing. Opportunity cost. Which I rather have them lose an upswing than lose 30% of their current stock. A loss means more than a gain. In a bond they still gain.

Comment: You caught me, I'm not in my 60s with a portfolio. I have my own plan, but I would not call myself a new grad, let alone a college student.. I get what you're trying to say.. but your solution is the one that's currently failing. Getting them a more competent advisor would be great but I fear they will just get themselves another bozo with conflicting interests. He even called yesterday to assure my parents they shouldn't do anything, sounds like all his customers are jumping ship?

Comment: Course, if they sold when I told them a month ago, they would be 20% better off. You all might be right, they probably waited too long. I'll probably be buying stock when it drops 10 bucks more for the dividends..  I'll talk to them about getting a better pro, but my parents tend to never fire people, like the horrible accountant they hate thats been ripping them off for years. I think it's a time issue with them.

Comment: More I think about it, you're probably right. Not like they plan to sell it off in 6 months anyways.. But I'll still try to get them more active in their management.

Comment: @StarWind bet ya anything he's he's not fee-only. In any case, you're  right, an adviser shouldn't be making trades for you. That's an old model from the days when info was limited and access was expensive. It sucked then too.

Comment: @patches Oh! I get it! Someone who just advises, but doesn't have the conflicted interest. There I go showing my inexperience again haha.  Yes this fellow holds the stocks and makes the trades. If we sell, he's out of work. I remember when we were getting my college funds out, Edward Jones really took us for every little fee you could think of. This time around I know I'll be doing it all myself.

Comment: @StarWind Yep. And this guy... I guess he takes a percentage of assets under management? If he got paid on commission he'd be eager to trade. So, having their money with him works the same way investing in mutual funds does -- they're giving their money to someone to invest for them, and letting that person take a piece as payment. In which case, what's the difference picking him or picking a mutual fund? cont...

Comment: Have you thought of presenting it to them that way? And then maybe showing them some charts of this guy's performance vs some solid mutual funds like VWELX or PRWCX? Usually people like your folks are scared to make the call on what to invest in -- they need someone to tell them it's ok. Or they don't know how to pick. But in this case, they DID decide what mutual fund to invest in -- the This Guy Mutual Fund.

Comment: My dad is an experienced investor, but he's not involved with these transactions. One of the accounts involves the extended family, which I think is the main source of hesitation. That's a good comparison. I'll have them do that! Thanks! I'm not sure what the deal specifically is with their guy, I do know that he lost a sizable amount in capital gains taxes by selling from the wrong account.  Good point, what good is a stock guy that just holds the same stock, and at this point they do not like "this guy" mutual fund haha.